# save still image (jpeg) from h.264 stream

Tags: c++, webcam, h.264, jpeg

Is it possible to save a jpeg image from a h.264 stream. I got the stream from a Webcam and would like to programm a little helper which saves the image on a keypress.

Would be great to get your help.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can do this. [This](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) is a good reference. Below is something I wrote up quick that worked for me:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  VideoCapture capture(0);
  namedWindow("video",1);
  while(capture.isOpened()){
    Mat frame;
    capture >> frame;
    imshow("video",frame);
    if (waitKey(30) > 0){
      imwrite("image.jpg",frame);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```